# Can I detect the display size/resolution in Emacs?

Tags: emacs, elisp, screen-resolution, xemacs

I'd like to change the window/frame size of my XEmacs based on the current display resolution.

This is useful when I run my laptop either by itself or attached to a docking station with an external monitor. In either situation, I'd like Emacs to detect the primary screen resolution and adjust its main window frame size accordingly when I start it up.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The current display resolution is available using the following functions (both non-interactive).

```
(x-display-pixel-width)
(x-display-pixel-height)
```

Comment: Exactly what I need. I intend to use the height to set the number of lines in my frame, and the width to position it within the display.

Answer (score 26):

For a more cross-platform solution, look at

```
(display-pixel-width)
(display-pixel-height)
```

If what you actually want to do is set the Emacs window to full screen on start-up, check out [maxframe.el](https://github.com/rmm5t/maxframe.el).

Comment: Unfortunately, these functions are not available in XEmacs.

Comment: Good to know, on both counts. I guess that with a couple of defalias, you could still use maxframe.el if you wanted.