# Get width of current monitor in Emacs Lisp

Tags: emacs, elisp

I have a two-monitor setup (running Ubuntu).

The Emacs Lisp function display-pixel-width gives me the combined width of the two monitors. How can I get the width of the current monitor (i.e., the monitor displaying the current frame)?

Comment: If all else fails, you could probably hack something together using the output from [xrandr](http://linux.die.net/man/1/xrandr).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### If you are using 24.3 or earlier:

> [display-pixel-width](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Display-Feature-Testing.html) is a compiled Lisp function in `frame.el'.
>
> (display-pixel-width &optional DISPLAY)
>
> Return the width of DISPLAY's screen in pixels. For character
>   terminals, each character counts as a single pixel.

### Additionally, if you are using 24.4 or later:

> ** [Multi-monitor support has been added](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Multiple-Terminals.html).
>
> *** New functions `display-monitor-attributes-list` and `frame-monitor-attributes`
>   can be used to obtain information about
>   each physical monitor on multi-monitor setups.

### Use an external process

You can also parse the output of [`xwininfo`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/xwininfo) or [`xrandr`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/xrandr) (use [`call-process`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Synchronous-Processes.html)).

### Maximize emacs

Finally, you can maximize emacs (either interactively or using [`modify-frame-parameters`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Parameter-Access.html); version 24.4 also has [`toggle-frame-fullscreen` and `toggle-frame-maximized`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Frame-Commands.html)) and query its frame size using [`frame-pixel-height` and `frame-pixel-width`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Size-and-Position.html).

### See also

1. [How do I find the display size of my system in Emacs?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3514299/850781)
2. [Can I detect the display size/resolution in Emacs?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2151449/850781)

Comment: No, I'm not using the development version. Perhaps what I want to do is not possible until the `*-monitor-attributes*` functions are available. I certainly have not been able to find an argument to `display-pixel-width` that would give me anything but the combined width of the monitors. Can you perhaps suggest a useful argument?

Comment: Thank you, @sds. I'll look into either using an external process or maximizing emacs. And then I'll eagerly await version 24.4. :-)

Answer (score 1):

`display-pixel-width` takes an argument to let you specify the display.  From its documentation (<kbd>C-h</kbd> <kbd>f</kbd> <kbd>display-pixel-width</kbd> <kbd>RET</kbd>):

> (display-pixel-width &optional DISPLAY)
>
> Return the width of DISPLAY's screen in pixels. For character
>   terminals, each character counts as a single pixel.

There's also the similar `x-display-pixel-width`, which may work if the above doesn't.

Comment: That doesn't work for me. According to the documentation, `x-display-pixel-width` may take a `nil` argument, in which case the selected frame's display will be used. Only, on my system I still get the combined width of the monitors when I do `(x-display-pixel-width nil)`, (I'm using emacs 24.2.1.)